# Render table columns that will fill full width.

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

Imagine window 1000px width. 
Four text columns 100px width. 
I want to make columns grow to 250px to fill full width.

I am using AutoSizer and MultiGrid.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Column` docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md) should have enough info for you to accomplish this. Basically you want something like this:

```
<Table width={1000} {...props}>
  <Column
    label='Name'
    dataKey='name'
    flexGrow={1}
    width={100}
  />
  {/* other columns ... */}
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if you are using AutoSizer, you can do something like that :

```
<AutoSizer>
{({width, height}) => (
    <Table height={height} width={width}>
        <Column width={width/4} className="MyColumn1" .../>
        <Column width={width/4} className="MyColumn2" .../>
        <Column width={width/4} className="MyColumn3" .../>
        <Column width={width/4} className="MyColumn4" .../>
    </Table>
)}
</AutoSizer>
```

AutoSizer provide 'width' and 'height' so you can use them like so. You can adjust the columns' width as you please using 'width' so it will depend on the container's width.

---

You must not use fixed values for your table if you use AutoSizer because it's goal is to provide you 'height' and 'width', so your table should use those values.

```
<Table width={1000} {...props}>
```

---

Answer (score -3):

Rather than using plugins, position your items with flexbox. You can learn it here:
http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: This answer probably tangential. Libraries like react-virtualized exist to limit the amount of data rendered to a page for performance reasons. I assume that OP is asking about layout within react-virtualized components because one of the concerns of his application is performance. Flexbox is nice for layout but doesn't address the more important performance constraint.